# Adobe Flash Builder (flex4): addChild() is not available in this class. 

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, loader, flash-builder, addchild

I want to load an swf into a flex 4 application in order to use its classes.

```
var ldr:Loader=new Loader();
ldr.load(new URLRequest("file://path/to/fileswf"));
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loaded);
function loaded(evt:Event):void { addChild(ldr); }
```

I receive the error:

> Error: addChild() is not available in this class. Instead, use addElement() or modify the skin, if you have one.
>    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/addChild()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:966]
>    at main/private:init/loaded()[C:\Documents and Settings\ufk\Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2\xpogames-toolkit-test\src\main.mxml:22]

If I change `addChild()` to `addElement()`, I receive the following compilation error:

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:Loader to an unrelated type mx.core:IVisualElement. main.mxml   path/dir line 22 Flex Problem

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well in flash builder 4 full version, there isn't any this.rawChildren.

The best approach to resolve the issue would be to convert each required class to a flex component and to use it on your flex application:

1. download and install flex component kit
   http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex_skins
2. create a movie clip
3. convert to flex component
4. add the relevant functions to this class

a skeleton for a class that is attached to a movieclip that is about to be converted to a flex component:

```
package {
import mx.flash.UIMovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
public dynamic class challenge_screen extends UIMovieClip {

    public function challenge_screen() {
        super();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: extending to a MovieClip and then adding to a UIComponent works too.

Answer (score 23):

Create another container to place the displayObject in:

```
// container ( IVisualElement ) for DisplayObjects
var container:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
addElement( container );

// displayObject goes to container
var displayO:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild( displayO );
```

Comment: Working great with Facebook Distractor from the ActionScript SDK. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott  Created a wrapping element I think.... I'd dig it out but I don't have access to that code any more, it was for an old job!

Answer (score 0):

this.rawChildren.addChild( ldr )
should work

Answer (score 0):

```
private var _loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
private var _uicomponent:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
private function swfLoaded(event:Event):void 
{
Alert.show("inside swf Loaded");
var content:DisplayObject =_loader.content;
_uicomponent.addChild(content);
} 
public function loadSWF () : void 
{   

_loader.addEventListener(Event.INIT, swfLoaded);
_loader.load("http://intelliveysoft.com:5080/myelearn/Admin.swf"); 
addElement(_uicomponent);
}
```

Try this. It will work

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.