# FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE mode: the "Allow" button click is passed to the application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, fullscreen, flash

In an AS3 game (using Flex 4.10.0) I would like to allow players to chat, even when they are [in fullscreen mode](http://www.leebrimelow.com/flash-player-11-3-fullscreen-keyboard-input/).

So I am using the following ActionScript code (the `_fullBox` checkbox triggers fullscreen mode in my web application):

```
public function init():void {
    if (stage.allowsFullScreenInteractive)
        stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, handleFullScreen, false, 0, true);
}

private function toggleFullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.displayState = 
        stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL ?
        StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE :
        StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
}

private function handleFullScreen(event:FullScreenEvent):void {
    _fullBox.selected = event.fullScreen;
}

<s:CheckBox id="_fullBox" click="toggleFullScreen(event)" label="Full Screen" />
```

This works in the sense that the fullscreen mode is entered successfully and users can use the keyboard to chat too.

Unfortunately, the click at the "Allow" button in the dialog (displaying "Allow full screen with keyboard controls?") is being passed down to the web application.

And in my case it resuls in the click at a playing table in the lobby as you can see in the screenshot and thus (unwanted) joining a game:

[image]

This (bug?) has been seen with Windows 7 / 64 bit and Flash Player 11,8,800,115.

Can anybody please share a good workaround for this?

I was thinking of adding a transparent `Sprite` or `UIComponent` above my web application, but the question is when (i.e. in which methods) to display/hide it?

**UPDATE:**

Calling `event.stopPropagation()` from `handleFullScreen()` doesn't help anything.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've submitted [Bug #3623333](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3623333) at Adobe.

**UPDATE 3:** A note to myself - `stage.allowsFullScreenInteractive` is useless, because only set when allready in fullscreen mode.

Comment: The only solution I see is to put a transparent layer (sprite, image, whatever) to stops clicks. Add it or remove it using the `FullScreenEvent`.

Comment: So create a "layer" in `toggleFullScreen()` and remove it in `handleFullScreen()`?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you need to create transparent layer to avoid undesired click events. you can hide this layer when screen returned to normal state or user accepted fullscreen state ([`FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FullScreenEvent.html#FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED) event will fired).

[Demo](http://nullpoint3r.freeiz.com/uploads/index.html) (flashplayer 11.3 required)

```
var transparentLayer:Sprite=new Sprite();
var timer:Timer = new Timer(50, 1);
init();
function init():void {
    transparentLayer.graphics.beginFill(0,0.1);
    transparentLayer.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
    transparentLayer.graphics.endFill();
    transparentLayer.visible=false;
    addChild(transparentLayer);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,handleTimerComplete);
    stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED,handleFSIA);
    _fullBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleFullScreen);
    stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, handleFullScreen);
}
function toggleFullScreen(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL){
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

        transparentLayer.visible=ExternalInterface.available;

    }else
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
}
function handleFullScreen(e:FullScreenEvent):void {
    _fullBox.selected = e.fullScreen;
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
        transparentLayer.visible=false;
}
function handleFSIA(e:FullScreenEvent):void{
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
}
function handleTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void{
    transparentLayer.visible=false;
}
```

Comment: I never worked with Flex, this post maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2996101/1696720

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, I updated my flash pro and build a demo for you. also i made changes in the code.

Comment: Awesome demo thanks. Too bad there is no FlexFiddle - similar to JSFiddle or SQLFiddle

Comment: This works great when your SWF is displayed in a browser with an HTML wrapper. But if someone uses a standalone SWF player, then the "Allow full screen with keyboard controls" never appears and your handleFSIA never gets called to remove the transparent layer. Is there a way to make it work whether your SWF is being displayed in an HTML or a standalone player?

Comment: Hi @BladePoint. you can use [`ExternalInterface.available`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#available) to check if the SWF is being displayed in an HTML or a standalone player

Comment: Maybe using `stage.allowsFullScreen` would be more straightforward than `ExternalInterface.available`? Also I wonder, why is `Timer` needed in the above source code?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, `stage.allowsFullScreen` property is true in both cases(if the swf is being displayed in a standalone player or an HTML wrapper with `<param name="allowFullscreenInteractive" value="true"/>` param). so you can't use this property to determine whether the transparentLayer must be shown or not.

Comment: +1 true, thanks and I've finally (6 months passed :-)) added your code to my Flex application here: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans (I've used a `Group` and a `Rect` instead of the translucent `Sprite`). And yes - the `Timer` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Found one workaround.

Allow and Cancel buttons are not the parts of the application, so when you hover one of those buttons you receive rollOut event for application.

```
<s:Application
    rollOut="application_rollOutHandler(event)"
    rollOver="application_rollOverHandler(event)">
```

Inside event handler you can disable mouse events for child objects. Don't disable for application as you won't get rollOver event after that.

```
private function application_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.mouseChildren = false;
}

private function application_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.mouseChildren = true;
}
```